# How to declare permission for Haptic classes (VibrationDevice) in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I've been using the [`VibrationDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.haptics.vibrationdevice) class from the Windows 10 Mobile extensions for a few months, but since I've updated my app to only target Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, I had to remive this extension and right now I can't find a way to implement the vibration APIs of the [`Windows.Devices.Haptics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.haptics) namespace in my app.

Here is a code snippet:

```
using Windows.Devices.Haptics;

if (await VibrationDevice.RequestAccessAsync() == VibrationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    VibrationDevice device = await VibrationDevice.GetDefaultAsync();
    if (device == null) return;

    // Do stuff with the device here
}
```

The code above always returns `VibrationAccessStatus.DeniedByUser`, and I couldn't find a method to explicitly ask the user for permission. So, I'm wondering if maybe I need to add some declaration to the app manifest, but I couldn't find any info in the docs about this.

I only found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-hid), but it only contains snippets to manually add to the app manifest. Checking that file, it says the file is auto-generated, so any changes there would be lost every time the app is recompiled, so I don't think this is the right solution. Using the built-in app manifest editor I couldn't find any capability to check related to either haptic feedback or human interactions.

I'm not sure about what to do here, does anyone know the steps needed to enable the usage of these new APIs in a UWP app?

Thanks!

Comment: "Note that your code should call RequestAccessAsync at least once, from the UI thread." got this from msdn. Hope you are doing the same

Answer (score 0):

***[Updated on 3/9/2018]***

> The code above always returns VibrationAccessStatus.DeniedByUser, and I couldn't find a method to explicitly ask the user for permission. So, I'm wondering if maybe I need to add some declaration to the app manifest, but I couldn't find any info in the docs about this.

To use the `Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice` class APIs, you do not need to add extra declaration in app manifest. If you found that your code always returns `VibrationAccessStatus.DeniedByUser` status, please check 'Windows Settings,Sounds | Vibrate' settings. If you turn off the Vibrate in 'Windows Settings,Sounds | Vibrate', it will always return the DeniedByUser. For example:

[image]

Here's a code sample that shows how to use the vibration device on supported hardware: [VibrationDevice Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/VibrationDevice). Please refer to it for more details.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I've removed the Mobile extension as W10 Mobile is stuck on the Feature2 branch and apps for the Fall Creators Update can't run on it, who will be able to use those Mobile extensions now? I mean, do they work for maybe some 2-in-1 devices too, or what? I mean, I didn't even check if a new Mobile extensions package existed since Windows 10 Mobile was never updates to the Fall Creators Update. Thanks!

Comment: I added the reference to 'Windows 10 Mobile extensions 16299' in my UWP project and used my above code to test on my windows 10 mobile(OS:15254). It worked well. So, please first try it.

Comment: My question was about apps targeting FCU, not the mobile extensions package specifically. I'm sure it works on W10M if you have a lower W10 version set as minimum, but my app targets FCU as both minimum and target, so it can't be deployed at all on W10M. Hence my question: As my app won't be aver be able to run on W10M now, is it worth it to still add this package and that code? That is, is there any kind of device other than W10M that can actually use those APIs in the mobile extensions package right now? Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio0694 The `Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification` is for windows phone devices. So, let's back to your original question. After a lot of testing with the `Windows.Devices.Haptics` namespace APIs, I found that if you turn off the `Vibrate` in 'Windows Settings,Sounds | Vibrate', it will always return the DeniedByUser. Please check this setting.